# How to use NumberPicker's textMapper(Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, numberpicker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Ut2.png)

I am trying to use textMapper to change the text shown in NumberPicker.

I found the TextMapper class, but I don't know how to use it.
Please tell me how to use textMapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its basically a method that takes a String argument and returns a String value that transforms the input.

eg:

```
String modifyText(String s){
  return "Value " +s; // Appends "Value" to the String s
}
```

Can be set to the `textMapper` property to show the values in the picker as "Value ..." instead of just '...'